# How to show java (jsf) generated pdf directly in AdobeReader

Tags: jsf, pdf-generation, jsf-2, acrobat, apache-fop

i am using JSF 2.0 (Eclipse IDE) and i have a method in one of my beans which generates some PDF files using Apache FOP 1.0. When I click "makePDF" button on my JSF page, generated PDF opens in the SAME window where my page is (and i have to use 'back' button after i view/save/print PDF).

I can change this in a way that when "makePDF" button is pressed, standard pop-out dialog appears and asks me if i wish to save file or to open it with AdobeReader.

Is there a way that, when i click my "makePDF" button, generated PDF is directly opened in AdobeReader (and i still have my JSF page and dont need to confirm anything) ??? Also (it's not really needed, but good to know), is there a way to open it in new window or send it directly to printer?

Here is the main part of my code (i deleted some irrelevant stuff) :

```
public void makePDF(long contractId, int documentType) {

    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    String basePath = externalContext.getRealPath("/");

    try {
        fopFactory.setUserConfig(new File(basePath + "/pdf_transform/config/userconfig.xml"));
        fopFactory.setBaseURL(basePath);
        fopFactory.getFontManager().setFontBaseURL(basePath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
    foUserAgent.setBaseURL(fopFactory.getBaseURL());

    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();
    response.reset();
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment");
    BufferedOutputStream output = null;

    try {
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), 10240);
        Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, output);

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltfile));

        Source src = new DOMSource(makeXML(contract)); // my method
        Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

        transformer.transform(src, res);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    facesContext.responseComplete();
}`
```

When i remove `response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment");` it opens in the same window, otherwise it asks me to save or open.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening a request in a new window is not directly a JSF concern. It's more a HTML concern.

Add `target="_blank"` to the form

```
<h:form target="_blank">
```

and it'll submit the request into a new tab/window.

Sending to the client's printer directly is not possible without introducing some piece of code which runs at the client side as man in the middle, like an applet.

Comment: Thanks, i missed that in your PDF Handling article because i concentrated on java code only :) Still, that doesn't answer my main question, ie can I open it directly in AdobeReader (not in the window) or i have to change my approach?

Comment: That's a browser setting which you cannot control. In Firefox for example, check *Tools > Options > Applications*.

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks. Although it turned out it wasn't really jsf/fop related, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to open a PDF directly, pls use

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and luckily found an elegant way to solve it. If someone has a better solution then please let me know.

Use case:
User enters data in a JSF generated form necessary for PDF creation (PDF is generated from a servlet). If validation fails, error messages are rendered but if everything goes fine pdf file opens in a new window.:-)

My solution:

1. In a template.xhtml (or the site which defines facelets) enter:

   ```
   <ui:define name="head">
           <h:outputScript rendered="#{myBean.pdfDownloadable}">
               window.open('#{myBean.pdfUrl}',"pdfWindow","width=800,height=900,left=50,top=10")
           </h:outputScript>
   </ui:define>
   ```
2. Your command link in the JSF-form points to action method in myBean as well (e.g. myBean.showPdf())
3. If form data are valid and showPdf() is called you can set the pdfDownloadable field to true and the same outcome is rendered again but this time with window.open() in it.

Hope it helps somebody..